# SQL Getting Data with extra row

Tags: sql

I have two tables with columns of my interests as Table1.Column1 and Table2.Column2
Table1 is Kind of a Group Table and Table2 is items table. The join query of these two tables gets the data in the followinf format

```
Column1   Column2
A         1
A         2
B         1
B         2
B         3
```

What I want is to get data in the following format:

```
Column1   Column2
A         0
A         1
A         2
B         0
B         1
B         2
B         3
```

i.e. getting extra 0 for each group at the start each time. The 0 does not exits in the database.

Does anyone know how to achive this in SQL?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Column1, [Column2] = 0
FROM    (
          YourOriginalQuery
        ) q
UNION ALL 
        YourOriginalQuery
```

Most likely, there are better solutions by incorporating this requirement into your original query. If you post your query, we can come up with better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Or something like:

```
select C.CategoryId, drv.CategoryGroupId from Category as C
cross join (
    select 0 as CategoryGroupId 
    UNION
    select CG.CategoryGroupId from CategoryGroup as CG
)drv order by CategoryId, CategoryGroupId
```